# Does multidimentional array indices calls a function to calculate the element adress in c?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, embedded, stm32

Assume I am working on ARM Cortex M7. Now take a look at:

```
int a[4][4];
a[i][j]=5;
```

Is in assembly language a function will be calculating the a[j][j] address or it uses lookuptable (pointer array with the same size) or some magical way to place `5` in correct place?

This is disassembler output:

```
136               array1[i][i+1]=i;
08000da6:   ldr     r3, [r7, #36]   ; 0x24
08000da8:   adds    r3, #1
08000daa:   ldr     r2, [r7, #36]   ; 0x24
08000dac:   uxtb    r1, r2
08000dae:   ldr     r2, [r7, #36]   ; 0x24
08000db0:   lsls    r2, r2, #2
08000db2:   add.w   r0, r7, #40     ; 0x28
08000db6:   add     r2, r0
08000db8:   add     r3, r2
08000dba:   subs    r3, #36 ; 0x24
08000dbc:   mov     r2, r1
08000dbe:   strb    r2, [r3, #0]
```

Comment: You could just look at the assembler output of your compiler. For constant numbers I would expect the compiler to calculate the offset during compilation and add the resulting value. Everything else would be a bit embarrasing I would say.

Comment: `a[2][3]` is equivalent to `*(a + (2 * 4) + 3)`.

Comment: What would a lookuptable gain? Calculating the offset into that table is not different from calculating the offset into the main array without any additional memory need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the indices as in your example, the compiler will calculate the exact memory address required at compile time.

If the indices were variables, then address would be calculated at run time.

Here is a [comparison of assembly output for both cases](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyahUAUgBMAIUtXyKxqiIEh1ZpgDC6egFc2TEAtydwAZAiZsADk/ACNsUhAAVnIAB3QlYhcmL19/QNT0zKEwiOi2OITkh2wnLJEiFlIiHL8AoOraoXrGohKo2Pik%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%2B4EclBEqXPciQwV%2BPDivcnIoWh37kPKPBaIqyr8NheE6os%2BoIPAPEQIa6BsCkDDxOaEAYMJokJI0bDMRYPACAwRDxBqEAxI%2BMThI0ACetr8JJHDCAA8kw9B6V6OBsMYwCSJZBCkDUzjvNgGpetg6g1D4Kn6ZQwgho%2B9AEDEpC6V4OCPkQpAEPKvC6jQRjAEoABqBDYIuxkpMwvn2qI4iSC6uXuhoj76IpfqmC%2BhjBRqkCLOgKSpm56ohk5WRuLGJaKaE0wJoMilZqmXUFCmWTNv1BZtV0da5AEillkWTa9XmBi1j0w1rZWy3VlIiyUu2zqMo56x8FiOJ4o%2BqrqOKMEALQwdI2zAKgqDbDwPC8tsECktYtgriaJCkJ%2BinbF4UmMEDlj0vMP74QBQEgdQbIKmhGHypBmEqtwOFavheqIAJaBCSJEPiZJJODLJ8mKZaKmkGpGlelprCkBZDKGcwRCmeZj5WTZdmEoQjm1C5bmEh5Xk%2BXFfkqbehJBSFYVYOshJRTF%2BmLAlLBJal6WZdl0u5Y6BWyEVKglV6PqGDZAa/UGCu1WBDVNdjk2dAEEadfWc0xnG22JgNhRDd7BiDWN/sTQt03rSH82te7FZTKUK3zTNGap0tyc7Twe3vpwQRRdgJ03udmPsdw113Q9T0vW9H0WF9P02EG2wA2Qn5BKDxPSR3MOcX%2B8PAYMYEQYqt4YWxT5qvYuG/iy9FyhyFi8hRPCkdI9I8Ik4pcmXU%2Bw1x%2BN8SghA0DQ4lG/lzqm/IxWevLSAauVj%2BnzQRA6VluGkI/%2BTf0or/v0/loM6d4LpYW4McAgZ9ti60XPEbYzwABKABZGur1mK8m5DwL6TAhDYABO8JQCCUFoLesRLBOC8F9zngRQCQ9QIgLRkkS40F7gwXFBYOC7Cd5by3nvDiGpcZcWRokHklweCcI3jBS44oeAwS0JyORaF7hgKxtPGhICGKTw4ho8gLl6btWkEAA%3D).

Comment: Thanks, But why there is two output for each code in that link?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd the top assembly is the output, the bottom is a difference view.

Answer (score 1):

Without considering optimization, the standard way a compiler implements a reference to an array element, say `x[k]`:

- Start with the memory address of `x`.
- Multiply the number of bytes in an element of `x` by `k`.
- Add that to the memory address of `x`.

Let’s suppose `int` has four bytes.

With `a[i][j]` of `int a[4][4]`, there are two memory references, so the address is calculated:

- Start with the memory address of `a`.
- The elements of `a` are arrays of 4 `int`, so the size of an element of `a` is 4 times 4 bytes, which is 16 bytes.
- Multiply 16 bytes by `i`.
- Add that to the address of `a`. Now we have calculated the address of `a[i]`.
- We use the address of `a[i]` to start a new calculation.
- `a[i]` is an array of `int`, so the size of an element of `a[i]` is 4 bytes.
- Multiply 4 bytes by `j`.
- Add that to the address of `a[i]`. This gives the address of `a[i][j]`.

Summarizing, if `s` is the start address of `a`, and we use units of bytes, then the address of `a[i][j]` is `s` + 16•`i` + 4•`j`.